# Vuejs/Node/Express Session ID workflow with OpenID

Tags: node.js, session, vue.js, openid-connect, express-session

I am having a tough time understanding how I'm supposed to implement sessions.

Currently I'm writing a Vuejs app and, somehow, have managed to evade implementing any kind of Oath2 "sign in with x" process, or at least have copy and pasted my way to success without understanding, I'm afraid.

Here's what I'm trying to do, and it actually works 90% of the way there.

I've implemented [passport-steam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-steam) and I can click through a Sign in to Steam button, login with my account, and get kicked back to my homepage. A `sessionID` cookie is set. This is how I have it all configured:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'topSecretKey!',
  name: 'sessionID',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
  returnURL: `${host}/auth/steam/return`,
  realm: host,
  profile: true, // enable profile exchange
  apiKey: ApiSettings.apiKey
}, (identifier, profile, done) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      // ...
      // fetch the user profile in the background, matching 
      // the steamID to the account
      profile.identifier = identifier
      return done(null, profile)
    })
  }
))

app.get('/auth/steam/return', passport.authenticate('steam', {
  failureRedirect: '/'
}), (req, res) => {
  console.log('sessionID=' + req.sessionID)
  console.log(`User logged in w/ Steam ID #${steamID}`)
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

I run all of this, I sign in, and check my Node console and all is well!

```
Found existing account.
sessionID=2YL_YdMrauNyZ-F0gnIv3XV_5sNFo4C9
User logged in w/ Steam ID #xxxxxx
```

But here begins my questions. `sessionID` is stored in the request object, this is clear.

1. Is the sessionID supposed to be used as a token when querying an OpenID-enabled API? (Steam API doesn't require anything other than the Steam ID which is returned plain as day.
2. Is the sessionID supposed to ever make it to the frontend? Currently I static-serve a /dist directory (again, this is Vue) so Node doesn't actually do much except handle API calls out to the SteamAPI. Of course, this doesn't actually require a sessionID... just an APIkey and the users SteamID which I store in their user profile on the Mongo side.
3. What is the pattern here? Am I supposed to put the users' sessionID in their user record in Mongo and ... pass it around? Seems strange to me to do it that way.
4. What's the procedure to check if a user is logged in? Check the cookie sessionID and make a request to return that user object to the frontend (using Vuex layer for quick retrieval).
5. An extension of #2, but in theory, is the sessionID *ever* supposed to make it to the frontend? The only data manipulation is happening in my Vuex stores - for example, adding a game for a user. How is the sessionID supposed to be used?

Thanks in advance - I know these questions are all over the place but I've been pulling my hair out!

**UPDATE August 2nd:**

Thanks to anyone who read - I had some developments last night that were definitely very helpful in understand how this workflow is supposed to go. Couple things I learned:

1. The sessionID is not supposed to be referenced on the frontend - it is passed back and fourth automatically between frontend and back to Node via the `request`
2. Rather than relying on a cookie (which keeps resetting the sessionID every time Node restarts) I set up a Mongo store using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo). This way my sessionID never actually changes until it naturally expires.
3. As for #4, checking if a user is logged in, I am just setting a cookie called loggedIn. I honestly can't think of a better way to do this, as the sessionID cookie is HTTP only, and thus, unavailable to any frontend Javascript/Vue in this case.
4. I've come to the understanding that the sessionID is to be used in the backend only, but I still am wondering if I'm supposed to connect it to the user some way. [This link](https://codepen.io/johnchristopherjones/post/setting-up-openid) was super helpful but I still feel as if my workflow is not perfect. When I do passport.serializeUser, what am I ideally supposed to pass to done() ? I am passing done(null, user.steamID) as the SteamAPI only requires the user SteamID to request their game list. Is this OK to do, or should I be passing the sessionID? Still confused!

**UPDATE AGAIN**
Great source of information [here](https://dzone.com/articles/securing-nodejs-managing-sessions-in-expressjs), regarding the security and the *why* behind all of the little details.